# Using a variable in a statement to reference the image stored in a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, variables, reference, uiimageview

UPDATED  Scroll down to see the question re-asked more clearly....
If I had the name of a particular UIImageView (IBOutlet) stored in a variable,  how can I use it to change the image that is displayed.  I tried this, but it does not work.

I'm still new to iphone programming, so any help would be appreciated.

```
NSString *TmpImage = @"0.png";
NSString *Tst = @"si1_1_2";

TmpImage = @"1.png";
UIImage *sampleimage = [[UIImage imageNamed:TmpImage] retain];


((UIImageView *) (Tst)).image = sampleimage;    // This is the line in question 
[sampleimage release];
```

RESTATED:

I have a bunch of images on the screen....   UIImageView   *s1, *s2 ,*s3  etc up to *s10

Now suppose I want to update the image each displays to the same image.
Rather than doing
     s1.image = sampleimage;
     s2.image = sampleimage;
          :
     s10.image = sampleimage;

How could i  write a for loop to go from 1 to 10   and then use
the loop var   as part of the line that updates the image.
   Something like this.
          for ( i = 1; i <- 10; ++i )
              s(i).image = sample;     // I know that does not work

Basic question is how do I incorporate the variable as part of the statement to access the image? Don't get hung up on my example. The main question is how to use a variable as part of the access to some element/object.

Bottom Line...  If I can build the name of a UIImageView into a NSString object,  How can I then use that NSString object to manipulate the UIImageView.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you casting a string to an image view?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't however think I did a very good job of  asking the question clearly to get what I was after.  My intention was not to cast the imageview as a string pointer. I will re ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh!  Your line in question:

```
((UIImageView *) (Tst)).image = sampleimage;
```

is casting a string pointer as a UIImageView pointer - you're basically saying that your pointer to a string is actually a pointer to a UIImageView!  It will compile (because the compiler will accept your assertion happily) but will of course crash on running.

You need to declare a variable of type UIImageView.  This can then hold whichever view you want to set the image of.  So your code could look like the following:

```
NSString *TmpImage = @"0.png";
UIImageView *myImageView;

If (someCondition == YES) {
    myImageView = si1_1_2;  //Assuming this is the name of your UIImageView
} else {
    myImageView = si1_1_3;  //etc
}

UIImage *sampleimage = [UIImage imageNamed:TmpImage];  //no need to retain it
myImageView.image = sampleImage;
```

Hopefully this makes sense!

**Edit**:  I should add, why are you trying to have multiple UIImageViews?  Because a UIImageView's image can be changed at any time (and in fact can hold many), would it not be better to have merely one UIImageView and just change the image in it?